# Override Lat Lon from draggable marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, geocode

I'm kinda new to Geocoding/API but am giving it a shot as I just need to do something which I thought would be simple. I have the following code which produces a map of Lat Lon from a device with a draggable marker. All good so far.

What I'd like to do is be able to override the Lat Lon fields by the new co-ordinates of where ever the Marker is dropped. I know I need to add an event listener in but not sure how to get the results to over write the existing Lat Lon fields.

Here is my simple code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Find me!</button>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
  mapholder.style.height='250px';
  mapholder.style.width='500px';

  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!",draggable: true});

  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {


    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```